# You can't be tweeting photos

Tags: expressions, time-reference

*"You can't be tweeting silly pictures of your grandfather like this. He is a respectable man."*

Please note that I made this sentence up so there might be mistakes. My question is about 'you can't be doing something.' What does it actually mean and when do you exactly say it?

Do you say this to tell someone not to do something they've already been doing?
I don't think it's possible to say it before someone does something, is it?

Comment: CAN'T BE [VERBING] is a relatively informal / dialectal usage, most stereotypically encountered in contexts like ***I can't be doing with that**! (I can't accept it, I want nothing to do with it).* It may be used deliberately by people who would normally avoid colloquialisms, in order to add a "folksy / bluff / plain-speaking" quality to the instruction / advice / order. But in "standard English" the cited example would use the bare infinitive rather than BE + VERBING - ***You can't tweet silly pictures...***

Answer (score 2):

It's idiomatic, to say that someone shouldn't engage in a behavior. You could use the phrase even before the person has done the behavior if you think there's a chance they will. For example, if your child is going off to college for the first time, you might say
"Remember, you can't be partying every night and still expect to get good grades."